# How do I apply dynamic styling to a specific item within a for:each loop using a unique identifier in the object data

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, dynamic

I am rendering a "timeline" made up of activity objects.(see below) I am using a for each loop to display them within a timeline component. Each object has a unique id. I want to add styling to a specific div using this id. I have a timer that runs for a determined amount of time and resets when that time is up then starts again for the next item in the timeline. I want to highlight which activity the timer is currently running for. I have a way to track the current time interval but not sure how to identify the specific object in the loop and add the styling. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<template>
<div class="timelineContainer">
  <template for:each={activityBlocks} for:item="activity" for:index="index">
    <lightning-layout class="activityLayout" key={activity.id}>
      <lightning-layout-item class="layoutItem">
        <div class="activityContainer">
          {activity.name}
        </div>
      </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
  </template>
</div>
```

```
activity = {
id: 001,
name: this.name,
duration: 30,
endtime: this.endtime};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part of it isn't working?  Where exactly are you stuck?  Please edit your question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the id, but in the `key`, it's not exposed. Add a data- attribute to keep track of which item is which.

```
<div class="activityContainer" data-id={activity.id}>
```

Which you can then query:

```
var activityContainer = this.template.querySelector(`div[data-id="${activity.id}"]`)
```

Comment: Ahhh! Perfect!! Thank you!!!